# TTTAttributedLabel addLinkToURL NSRange confusion

Tags: xcode, swift, hyperlink, tttattributedlabel

I am making a swift app and I want to add a url to a TTTAttributedLabel. I have got addLinkToUrl but it wants a NSRange. What should I put. I am new to swift. I want the url to be for the entire text.

```
//PersonTalking is a TTTAttributedLabel
        var characterSpeaking:NSDictionary = item["characterspeaking"] as NSDictionary
        var characterSpeakingString:String = characterSpeaking["text"] as String
        var characterHref:String = characterSpeaking["href"] as String
        var characterUrl = NSURL(string: characterHref)
        println(characterSpeakingString)
        PersonTalking.text = characterSpeakingString

        PersonTalking.addLinkToURL(characterUrl, withRange: )
```

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the link is meant to include the full label, then your range should be the full length of your text.

```
PersonTalking.addLinkToURL(characterUrl, 
                           withRange:NSMakeRange(0,
                                                countElements(characterSpeakingString))
```

Comment: Thanks. I used .utf16